# Independence Number and Shannon Capacity of Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, bipartite-graphs

Let $\alpha(G)$ denote the independence number of $G$ and $S(G)$ the Shannon capacity. Show that for every bipartite graph $G$, $\alpha(G)=S(G)$.

This seems to be true, but I'm not sure how to proceed with a rigorous proof. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit 1: Does the result follow from König's Theorem?

Comment: Depends on what you know and what tools you are trying to learn to use. Maybe you want a low-level proof - in which case, apply the definition of Shannon capacity. Maybe you want a high-level proof - in which case, prove that bipartite graphs are perfect. There's really nothing else to be said in response to a question where you have done nothing.

Comment: @MishaLavrov How would you do this from the definition of Shannon capacity? I know that Shannon capacity is always greater than or equal to the independence number. Do we have to sandwich with the Lovász theta function?